# Find all paths from source to target in given depth

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I currently use networkx and find paths like this

`paths = networkx.all_simple_paths(g, source, target, depth)`

But this return only **simple** paths(no repeated nodes), my goal is find **all** possible paths in **given depth** from source to target.
What the easiest method to do this?

Code example:

```
import networkx as nx


def create_edges():
    edges = []
    edges.append('A-B')
    edges.append('B-C')
    edges.append('C-B')
    edges.append('C-D')

    return edges


def get_paths(source, target, depth):
    edges = create_edges()

    g = nx.Graph()
    nodes = []
    for node in edges:
        n1 = node.split('-')[0]
        n2 = node.split('-')[1]

        if n1 not in nodes:
            nodes.append(n1)

        if n2 not in nodes:
            nodes.append(n2)
    for node in nodes:
        g.add_node(node)
    for edge in edges:
        n1 = edge.split('-')[0]
        n2 = edge.split('-')[1]

        g.add_edge(n1, n2)

    paths = nx.all_simple_paths(g, source, target, depth)
    path_list = [path for path in paths]

    return path_list


res = get_paths('A', 'D', 5)
print(res)
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]    What I get
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D']]  What I want
```

Comment: If you allow repeated nodes, aren't there infinite numbers of paths? Please clarifiy your question with examples.

Comment: @timgeb no, because I set maximum allowed depth(for example 5, so, path cant repeat one cycle infinity times in path

Comment: I think I understand. I don't think networkx has a builtin function for that. But I think you can start with the simple paths and extend them with (up to) depth - path_length unnecessary nodes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use modified library code. The function `all_simple_paths` calls:

```
def _all_simple_paths_graph(G, source, targets, cutoff):
    visited = dict.fromkeys([source])
    stack = [iter(G[source])]
    while stack:
        children = stack[-1]
        child = next(children, None)
        if child is None:
            stack.pop()
            visited.popitem()
        elif len(visited) < cutoff:
            if child in visited:
                continue
            if child in targets:
                yield list(visited) + [child]
            visited[child] = None
            if targets - set(visited.keys()):  # expand stack until find all targets
                stack.append(iter(G[child]))
            else:
                visited.popitem()  # maybe other ways to child
        else:  # len(visited) == cutoff:
            for target in (targets & (set(children) | {child})) - set(visited.keys()):
                yield list(visited) + [target]
            stack.pop()
            visited.popitem()
```

<strike>I think you should get the desired paths by removing the:</strike>

```
if child in visited:
    continue
```

condition and initializing visited with empty dict instead of:

```
visited = dict.fromkeys([source])
```

I didn't test it, though

The previous idea didn't work. I'll stick to library code networkx code, but I think at this point I could also write it from scratch:

```
def _all_simple_paths_graph(G, source, targets, cutoff):
    # as you noted it the comment you need a list
    visited = [source]
    stack = [iter(G[source])]
    while stack:
        children = stack[-1]
        child = next(children, None)
        if child is None:
            stack.pop()
            # replace all `popitem` with `pop`
            visited.pop()
        elif len(visited) < cutoff:
            if child in targets:
                yield list(visited) + [child]
            # append instead of assignment
            visited.append(child)
            if targets - set(visited):
                stack.append(iter(G[child]))
            else:
                visited.pop()
        else:  # len(visited) == cutoff:
            for target in (targets & (set(children) | {child})) - set(visited):
                yield list(visited) + [target]
            stack.pop()
            visited.pop()
```

It worked for your example and found one more solution:

```
[['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

You should call it like this:

```
_all_simple_paths_graph(g, source, {target}, depth)
```

Comment: its don't work because visited used for storage path `yield list(visited) + [child]`. visited - dict, so, this cant store path with repeated nodes, and `len(visited) < cutoff` doesn't work when cycle in path. I tried to make list `visited` instead of dict, but I still couldn't reach my goal

Comment: You are right - I updated the answer.